# WebView in Dialog

Tags: android, android-webview, android-dialog

I have an application where I need to load a small webpage inside of webview. The webview needs to load up inside a dialog.
I've tried to implement it; but everytime an empty dialog loads up and seems to have no content inside it. The code i've used is below

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getLink());
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webviewdialog, null);
dialog.setContentView(v);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
WebView wb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wb.loadUrl(uri.toString());
dialog.show();
```

I've also tried putting in urls directly inside loadUrl, but I get the same issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setView(webView);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Okay", null);
    dialog.show();
```